# SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 3850)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I get above mentioned error on some devices (very rarely, 2 times until now only):

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 3850)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForString(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:679)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:361)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:236)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:200)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
    at ***.a(***.java:115)
```

The line 115 in my code is following:

```
// here the exception occurs
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(pathApp, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY); 
// ...
db.close();
```

**Story**

What I do is following:

- app has root rights
- it copies the database from another app into it's own directory
- it tries to open this database and read some data
- it close the file again

That's all. This is working on thousands of devices. My app for sure only accesses the database at on place, I'm completely sure about that

**Question**

Does anyone know what could cause this problem?

**Maybe interesting facts**

- the 2 devices are a OnePlus2
- one guy told me that the problem occurred after updating to Oxygen 2.1

Comment: I am suddenly getting user reports of this error as well (since September 25; before that it never appeared). All of the instances are on a ONE device and running Android 5.1.1. Perhaps that device received a recent system update that caused this?

Comment: the two devices I know of that are effected did get a system update... to Oxygen 2.1... But I don't know anything more about it... And did not find anything yet...

Comment: Finally found a solution :-). Add the sqlite binaries to your app, find out which one is working on the device and DUMP the database to the console and parse the output... This is working even on the OnePlus2

Comment: Surprisingly i am having the same problem with OnePlus2

Comment: @prom85, how'd u do it.. could u elaborate your answer.. (we can continue this over chat)

Comment: I wrote a complete answer... Just check it out

Comment: FWIW, I see this when I reboot the device in the middle of a database transaction. DB seems fine after reboot. Maybe ignore this one. https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#ioerr_lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working solution (already tested in production for 2 months now or so) and this works on the OnePlus2 and on Android 6 as well:

- add the `sqlite` binaries to your app (can be found here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2730422). Just put them into your apps assets folder

Then in your app, try to read an external database like following:

- Find out which binary is working. I tried a few methods (via calling `/proc/cpuinfo`for example) but could not find a reliable solution, so I do it via trial and error like following:

  - First I copy the binary from my assets folder to my apps `files` folder
  - Then I try to dump the desired database via `<path_to_SQLite3_bnary> <path_to_database> \.dump '<tablename>'\n` and read the result
  - I check the result, if it contains `error:` I know the binary is not working, if it starts with `INSERT INTO` I know it works
  - I repeat this with my binaries until I found a working binary
- Then I just read the result. The result will contain an error or be some csv similar content. I either handle the error or convert every line to valid csv via `row.replace("INSERT INTO \"" + tablename + "\" VALUES(", "").replace(");", "")`, so that I get the content in a `csv` format. I use opencsv's `CSVReader` to parse the data then...

That's it, this works (until know) on all devices without a problem

**Code - copied from my sources, adopt it a little bit to fit your needs**

```
public static List<String> readCSVData(String pathDatabase, String tableName) throws InterruptedException, TimeoutException, RootDeniedException, IOException 
{
    List<String> res = null;
    List<String> csvData = null;

    final String[] architectures = new String[]{
            "armv7",
            "armv7-pie",
            "armv6",
            "armv6-nofpu"
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < architectures.length; i++)
    {
        res = readDatabase(architectures[i], pathDatabase, tableName, rootMethod);

        if (res.toString().contains("[error:"))
        {
            L.d(RootNetworkUtil.class, "Trial and Error - ERROR: " + architectures[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            int maxLength = (res.toString().length() < 100) ? res.toString().length() : 100;
            L.d(RootNetworkUtil.class, "Trial and Error - RESULT: " + res.toString().substring(0, maxLength));
            L.d(RootNetworkUtil.class, "Architecture found via trial and error: " + architectures[i]);
            csvData = res;
            break;
        }
    }

    return csvData;
}

private static List<String> readDatabase(String architecture, String pathDB, String tablename) throws InterruptedException, TimeoutException, RootDeniedException, IOException {
    String sqlite = "sqlite3." + architecture;
    String pathSQLite3 = getSQLitePath(architecture, tablename);
    // OWN class, just copy the file from the assets to the sqlite3 path!!! 
    AssetUtil.copyAsset(sqlite, pathSQLite3);

    String[] cmd = new String[]{
            "su\n",
            //"chown root.root " + pathSQLite3 + "\n",
            "chmod 777 " + pathSQLite3 + "\n",
            pathSQLite3 + " " + pathDB + " \".dump '" + tablename + "'\"\n"
    };
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> temp = RootUtils.execute(cmd);
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++)
    {
        // Fehlerzeilen behalten!!!
        if (temp.get(i).contains("error:"))
            res.add(temp.get(i));
        else if (temp.get(i).startsWith("INSERT INTO \"" + tablename + "\""))
            res.add(temp.get(i).replace("INSERT INTO \"" + tablename + "\" VALUES(", "").replace(");", ""));
    }
    return res;
}

public static String getSQLitePath(String architecture, String addon)
{
    String sqlite = "sqlite3." + architecture;
    String pathSQLite3 = "/data/data/" + MainApp.get().getPackageName() + "/files/" + sqlite + addon;
    return pathSQLite3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar problem recently where my app runs fine on all Android devices except the OnePlus Two running OxygenOS 2.1.

After looking into the issue, it appears this specific combination is very sensitive and crashes on a database lock of some sort. In my case, my app was copying a new database to the device on the first run then checking the database version to see if it requires an update. On the check it crashed on these devices. I realized in my code I am opening a separate instance to the database instead of using the currently opened database when checking the version. After changing the code to avoid opening a separate instance of the database, the app stopped crashing on the OnePlus.

My advice is to Not open multiple instances of the database in your app or try closing the database first before opening it again (perhaps your copy method didn't close the database or is using another instance of the same database).

Comment: my copy method copies the file as a stream so any internal flags will stay as before... How could I close the database after copying the file? I'm copying a file from a different app (my app has root rights) and I copy it to my directory so that I can read it with `SQLiteDatabase`...

Comment: In my app I am copying as a stream as well but this is happening within the same app and from within another function that tries to open the database first to check if it exists then CLOSES it then copies it as a stream. So make sure it is closed before it is copied over.

Comment: I can't... I have no control over the database file... Maxbe I can somehow directly close it via sqlite3... I have to check that...

Comment: Instead of copying it as is, try dumping the original database as an sql file and importing it to your app as a new database file then copying it over - this way you have a fresh copy of it without worrying about flags and other issues.

Comment: For android 6 I have to anyway add the sqlite3 binary to my app and use it... I tried it with that as well, but currently (still waiting for further feedback) this fails on this specific device as well... I'll try if the dump succeeds and try to read the dumped file afterwards

Comment: The dumping solution works! Reading via the console and `sqlite -csv ...` fails, copying the database and manipulating all permissions fails, but dumoing via console with `sqlite db .dump 'tablename' ` is working. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered this in development.  It triggered when the phone ran out of batteries and shut down.  Presumably, you just have to be grabbing the database lock when that happens.